# Is there any code for local-orbital ab initio tight binding molecular dynamics other than fireball?

Tags: density-functional-theory, software, reference-request, software-recommendations

I was searching for a local-orbital ab-initio tight binding implementation of molecular dynamics and Ive found a code called [fireball](https://sites.google.com/site/fireballofficialsite/). Ive tried to compile it but the code seems to be buggy and there is no manual.

Is there any code similar to the one mentioned above?

Comment: Did you see this fork: [https://github.com/ProkopHapala/Fireball-progs](https://github.com/ProkopHapala/Fireball-progs)?

Comment: Jason.
I have similar questions. Could I ask if there are any other materials useful for the fireball? Or other tight-binding molecular dynamics software? If possible. Thanks, Jian Gao

Comment: I believe that you should check out SIESTA: https://departments.icmab.es/leem/siesta/ , and If you're also interested in a semi-empirical approach, you can consult with DFTB+: https://dftbplus.org/

Comment: XTB uses a semi-empirical tight binding approach: https://github.com/grimme-lab/xtb. However, the periodic boundary condition implementation is not fully implemented in the current version.

Comment: If any of these listed options seem like what you are looking for, just reply and I can reopen the question so someone can provide an answer with a short description of the program.

Comment: Likewise if any of those options were *not* helpful, you can reply and probably get the question re-opened. I think the problem is that you ignored people's comments, which made this look like an "abandoned" question.